# How to display a message if empty string found using num_rows, Object-Oriented procedural, in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I have a MySQL table with 3 columns (city, color, votes).
I have an HTML table with colors, some of these colors don't exist in the MySQL table. I am trying to display "0" if there is not a match.
I receive "" in the console when the color doesn't exist, but I want to display "0" in the HTML table for these colors.
Any idea?

I have this php so far:

```
$co = $_REQUEST['color'];

$sql = "SELECT SUM(votes) AS sum FROM Votes WHERE color = '$co'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["sum"];
    }
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

and this is the ajax call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#red').on('click', function() {
        var colorId = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            "url": "tables.php", 
            "data": {"color" : colorId}, 
            success: function(response) {
                $("#redr").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#orange').on('click', function() {
        var colorId = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            "url": "tables.php", 
            "data": {"color" : colorId}, 
            success: function(response) {
                $("#oranger").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#green').on('click', function() {
        var colorId = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            "url": "tables.php", 
            "data": {"color" : colorId}, 
            success: function(response) {
                $("#greenr").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#indigo').on('click', function() {
        var colorId = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            "url": "tables.php", 
            "data": {"color" : colorId}, 
            success: function(response) {
                $("#indigor").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });


    $('#yellow').on('click', function() {
        var colorId = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            "url": "tables.php", 
            "data": {"color" : colorId},
            success: function(response) {
                $("#yellowr").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#blue').on('click', function() {
        var colorId = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            "url": "tables.php", 
            "data": {"color" : colorId}, 
            success: function(response) {
                $("#bluer").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#total').on('click', function() {
        var sumofval = 0;
        $(".val").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() !== '') {
                sumofval = sumofval + parseInt($(this).text());
            }
            $('#totalr').text(sumofval);
            console.log(sumofval);
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: So what, Exactly, is the problem here?

Comment: That query will return only ONE Row. So you dont need the while loop to fetch it just the `fetch_assoc()`. Then someone looking at your code will know you are processing only one result row. _Self Documentation_

Comment: RiggsFolly, kk, I have 2 columns (colors, votes) in a html table. Colors column are links in the html table. When you click on each of them, the votes of that color are displayed via ajax, but some of those colors are not present in the mysql table. I want to display "0" in the table when that happens. By now, I only receive "<empty string>" in the browser console when the color is not present. Does that makes sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the result of your query before passing back a value.

A SUM() query will Always return a row and only one row, so you have to check the result and then if it is null (no value for the sum) echo a zero otherwise echo the number from the sum()

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(votes) AS sum FROM Votes WHERE color = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// assumed `color` was a string column, 
// if its integer is `'i'` instead of `'s'`
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_REQUEST['color']);
$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->get_result();

$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['sum'] == '' ? 0 : $row['sum'];
```

> Note: I also changed your  code to use a prepared query with bound values. This is far more secure than the concatenated value mechanism you were using to avoid [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: RiggsFolly, how is this process called? the one that begins int line 4 of your snippet. Until now I have just learned to fetch data, kind of, with if, else statements.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this.

```
$('#red').on('click', function() {
  var colorId = $(this).attr("id");

  $.ajax({"url": "tables.php", "data": {"color" : colorId}, success: function(response) {
    response = Number(response)
    response = response.toFixed(0)
    $("#redr").text(response);
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

It uses `.text()` rather than `.html()`. And it turns a possible blank response from your php web endpoint into an actual number.

I used two lines of code to do that because of the Redmond Middle School Science Project known as Internet Explorer.  Here's what those lines do:

It's possible coming in to the ajax callback that `response` is an actual number, or a text string containing a number, or an empty text string, or a null value. `response = Number(response)` forces it to be a number. In the empty or null cases, the number comes out zero.

The second line `response = response.toFixed(0)` converts the number back to a text string, with zero digits after the decimal point.

Then giving that text string to `.text(response)` puts it into your web page at the appropriate place.

If it weren't for Internet Explorer you could do

```
... .text(Number(response).toFixed(0))
```

all in one line. But IE can't cope with using the `.toFixed()` method on anything but an actual declared variable. Plus, the extra lines are slightly easier to explain.

**Pro tip** Always indent your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, O. Jones, it worked. Can you explain me a little bit how those 2 lines you get the result I wanted? I want to understand it more clearly.

Comment: O. Jones, ok, but why do I need to turn it back to a text string?

Comment: If it's already a nonempty text string you're all set. But you'd have to detect that situation and handle it conditionally. The code I suggested does what you need without any ifs or ternaries.